# Succeed in OR to + noun/gerund/infinitive?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

**TIL**: the phrase **["succeed in + noun/gerund"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/succeed+in+(something))** means:

- *to complete or accomplish something as one desires, hopes, or intends.*
- *to find success in some job, role, endeavor, opportunity, etc.*

and the phrase **["succeed to + noun/gerund"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/succeed+to+(something))** means:

- *to take over some title, throne, or position in place of someone else as designated by the political, royal, or corporate hierarchy.*

According to the meanings above; thus:

> 1. The king **succeeds in** the throne.
>
> > This means ***the king does his job very well in his reign.***
>
> 2. The king **succeeds to** the throne.
> 3. The king **succeeds to** *claim* the throne.
> 4. The king **succeeds in** *claiming* the throne.
>
> > These mean the same as ***the king claims the throne successfully.***

**Do they have any other differences??**

`Thank you very much`

Comment: I fail to see how this is substantively different than [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184684/fail-in-or-to) here, or [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/471614/291924) post on ELU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*succeed* has two primary meanings, and your sentences contain examples of both of them. From [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/succeed):

> 1 Achieve the desired aim or result.

When used in the active form, this is often followed by "in" followed by a verb phrase, as in sentence #2.

> 2.1 Become the new rightful holder of an office, title, or property.

This is the sense in your sentence #3.

Sentence #1 is grammatically correct, but when "succeed in" is followed by a noun phrase, it's usually an endeavor of some kind that you can be successful in, e.g. "succeeds in the game". A throne is not an endeavor, and we would not normally say "succeeds in the throne" (although it would probably be understood as meaning that he is a successful ruler).

Sentence #4 is not acceptable, we don't usually follow "succeed" by an infinitive.

By [Barma](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/66603/barmar)